# Strike through on specific list item - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm very new to using jQuery. I've made a very basic shopping list with an add item and clear all function. But I'd like to add in a strike through function, so that when someone clicks on a specific item they've added it strikes through like it's completed. I've tried using

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Shopping List.</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="header2">
        <h2>What I need:</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
        <input id="name" type="text">
        <button id="addOne">Add</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>


    <div id="footer">2016</div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>"
    <script>
        $("#addOne").click(function() {
            var value = $("#name").val();
            $("ul").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
            });
        $("#clear").click(function(){
            $("ul").empty();
        });

        $("#list").click(function(){
            $(this).wrap("<strike>");
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

but all the list items will strike through. Would is be better in JavaScript? 
And how would I write it so that on click, if it has a strike through, it will un-strike?

Comment: _"how would I write it so that on click, if it has a strike through, it will un-strike?"_ : Rather than `.wrap("<strike>")` or `.css('text-decoration', 'line-through');` I would use `.toggleClass('purchased')` so the class _purchased_ is added if not present, or removed if already present — then style `li.purchased { text-decoration: line-through; }`

Comment: Oh thats nice and simple too :D cheers

Comment: that works really well :D @StephenP ideal :D cheers for that !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is because the items are added later so you need to handle the "li" like this (see below)

```
$("#list").on("click", "li", function(){
    $(this).wrap("<strike>");
});
```

Comment: Is there a simple solution to removing the strike through if clicked again or is that  an if else statement?

Comment: Nice simple solution, but very bad practice; seriously, don't use `<strike>` ... _strike_ is deprecated; html5 uses `<s>` and as the [w3c](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/s.html) says, it's for "contents that are no longer accurate".  @lmutton your click has a meaning: "I purchased this" or "it's in my cart" so represent that state using a class as I commented on the question. Then decide how you want to style that ... maybe strike-through, maybe background color change. What is important is the _information_ that you have "completed" that item.

Comment: @lmutton, Rayon's decoration will work with class and jquery toggle, search for it, and btw good point Stephen

Answer (score 2):

> Use `text-decoration: line-through;`, *Defines a line through the text*

You can use [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) if you want to `toggle` the `style` or `.css(STYLE)` will do, *Add or remove one or more classes from each element in the set of matched elements*

**HTML `<strike>` Tag. Not Supported in HTML5.**

*Note:* Use [`event-delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for `li(dynamic)` elements as those are your target elements not parent `UL` element.

```js
$("#addOne").click(function() {
  var value = $("#name").val();
  $("ul").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
});
$("#clear").click(function() {
  $("ul").empty();
});

$("#list").on('click', 'li', function() {
  //-------^^---------^^^^^ // .on method is used to bind the event on dynamic elements
  $(this).toggleClass('strike');
});
```

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="header">
  <h1>Shopping List.</h1>
</div>
<div id="header2">
  <h2>What I need:</h2>
</div>
<div id="list">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
<input id="name" type="text">
<button id="addOne">Add</button>
<button id="clear">Clear</button>


<div id="footer">2016</div>
```

Comment: You call out `text-decoration: line-through;` but ***much more important*** is the fact that you are handling clicks on the `<li>` where the OP was handling clicks on the `<ul>` and that almost gets lost in your answer. Some people might not notice it at all.

Comment: another good point is that the "li" are missing in the original html structure

Comment: @vtz, `li` elements are being appended dynamically!

Comment: yes, my point is that this is why .click() is not working in the original post even if the elements are catched ("#list li") P.S @RayonDabre i comment on your answer because this was not mentioned :) that is all

Comment: @vtz, Thanks for pointing it! I do miss key points many of the times ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a fully encapsulated "clear all" function, use:

```js
$('#clear').click(function() {
  $('#list > ul > li').css({
    textDecoration: 'line-through'
  });
});
```

If you are looking for an action "so that when someone clicks on a specific item" to have a strike through on that item, then use:

```js
$('#list > ul > li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css({
    textDecoration: 'line-through'
  });
});
```

If you want to use a class, then:

```js
$('#list2 > ul > li').on('click', function () {
    $(this).addClass('strike');
});
```

**Working Sample:**

```js
$('#clear').click(function() {
  $('#list > ul > li').css({
    textDecoration: 'line-through'
  });
});


$('#list > ul > li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).css({
    textDecoration: 'line-through'
  });
});

$('#list2 > ul > li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('strike');
});
```

```css
.strike {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="list">
  <ul>
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="list2">
  <ul>
    <li>First Item</li>
    <li>Second Item</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<button type="button" id="clear">Strike Out</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the list items will strike through because you specified the `.wrap` for the `div`with id `#list` – which encompasses the entire list (`<ul>...</ul>`).

Instead, you need to register the function for each individual `li` element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

register a click event for each li you append.
[See example on Code pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNXKwb)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#addOne").click(function() {
        var value = $("#name").val();
          var $listItem = $("<li striked=false>" + value + "</li>");
          $listItem.click(function(){

            if($(this).attr('striked')=='true'){
              $(this).attr('striked', 'false');
              $(this).removeClass('strike-through');
            } else {
              $(this).attr('striked', 'true');
              $(this).addClass('strike-through');
            }

          });
          $("#list > ul").append($listItem);
        });

        $("#clear").click(function(){
          $("#list > ul").empty();
        });
});
```

CSS:

```
.strike-through{
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.3.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Shopping List.</h1>
    </div>
    <div id="header2">
        <h2>What I need:</h2>
    </div>
    <div id="list">
        <ul></ul>
    </div>
        <input id="name" type="text">
        <button id="addOne">Add</button>
        <button id="clear">Clear</button>


    <div id="footer">2016</div>

</body>
```

Comment: @lmutton notice how i performed the select for ul? if you have many ul tags on your page, then you need to be specific as to which ul you are selecting. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
$("#addOne").click(function() {
        var value = $("#name").val();
        $("ul").append("<li>" + value + "</li>");
        });
    $("#clear").click(function(){
        $("ul").empty();
    });

    $("#list").click(function(){
        $(this).wrap("<strike>");
    });
```

to

```
$(function(){
$("#addOne").click(function() {
    var value = $("#name").val();
    $("ul").append("<li class='listitem'>" + value + "</li>");
    addListner();
    });
    $("#clear").click(function(){
        $("ul").empty();
    });
            function addListner(){
    $(".listitem").click(function(){
        $(this).css('text-decoration', 'line-through');
    });
    };
});
```